# HERE.com Routing API: tollroad mileage calculation

Tags: routes, here-api

I'm using HERE.com Routing API to calculate truck path using coordinates from truck GPS tracker. So I don't need to build the optimized route or whatever but just define what the route was passed by the truck: road number, state, mileage etc. All is ok excepting tollroads in some places.

In particular I have problems with the next points:

**Point 1: latitude: 33.99045, longitude: -84.0827401**

**Point 2: latitude: 33.94223, longitude: -84.151**

Both of them are on I-85 road in GA. I use REST API method *routing/7.2/calculateroute.json* to build leg between them with *mode=fastest;carHOV;traffic:disabled;tollroad:-2* including links attribute. For some reason every link in result contains *flags: [ 'tollroad', 'motorway' ]*. But this road is not toll. It has just toll express lane.

Is there some way to recognize this situation using your API? Because I need to calculate precise toll mileage for truck.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to recognize this scenario because we have no such detailed lane level information, but just for the road as a whole, therefore the service includes the "tollroad" flag since it is detected.

By the way the consumer routing 7.2 is not the proper service for truck purposes since truck data is not supported. Only the enterprise version 6.2 supports trucks.

Comment: Hmm... You think it is right to recognize the entire road as toll if it has just one toll lane?

Comment: Hello, I need to rectify my answer. I got confirmation that we have truck service now in 7.2 though currently a Beta.
Also, there was an issue with toll road marking in a recent map and we reported the issue in order to fix it, I am trying to reproduce the issue now but without success:

http://route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&mode=fastest;carHOV;traffic:disabled;tollroad:-2&waypoint0=33.9045,-84.0827401&waypoint1=33.94223,-84.151&legattributes=all&linkattributes=all&maneuverattributes=all